# [JIRA Hide button comment automatically

Tags: button, comments, hide, jira

I am using Jira version 6.0.7.
In permission scheme, I have already settings the "Add comments" with Current Assignee.
So, all I need is, when someone got the task, only he/she can add comments and I already can do that.

The problem is, when he/she have done their task which is will route to next assignee, he/she still can add comments before refresh the page (the below comment button still appears, the upper comment button has gone).

Is that any script to do auto refresh page for JIRA, or any solutions for my case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to post a bug issue to Atlassian.
But did you try to use the "no disappeared comment button" ? I thought that, even your user can see the "Comment" button, he/she has no right anymore to post any comment : he/she will obtain have a "no permission" error message.